# Woo Commerce Subscription Switch Automatic / Manual Payment by End User

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

Actually I am using Woo Commerce Subscription Plugin.
I need that when any user will come our website to purchase anything then he must have option to pay manually or automatically for the simple subscription product.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need to integrate on front end then you must need to do the editing as per your requirement.
But if you need to know how to make subscription option like manually or automatically on front end by doing the customization you just need to check the below link.

https://support.woothemes.com/hc/en-us/articles/203159667-Change-a-Subscription-from-Automatic-to-Manual-Payments

Thanks